# Retrieve unique rows based on multiple parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

This may be quite simple but I seem to lacking the proper way to phrase this question via search engines.

For a given TicketId there are unique identifiers based on LocId AND BinId. There can also be any number of TransIds for any given LocId + BinId combination.

What I need is to return only the records with the highest TransId.

```
TicketId | LocId | BinId | TransId
-------- | ----- | ----- | -------
316      | 111   | 100   | 1000
316      | 112   | 101   | 1001
316      | 113   | 105   | 1000
316      | 104   | 210   | 1001
316      | 104   | 210   | 1000
316      | 17    | 35    | 1000
316      | 17    | 35    | 1001
316      | 27    | 99    | 1001
```

So my expected results would be:

```
TicketId | LocId | BinId | TransId
-------- | ----- | ----- | -------
316      | 111   | 100   | 1000
316      | 112   | 101   | 1001
316      | 113   | 105   | 1000
316      | 104   | 210   | 1001
316      | 17    | 35    | 1001
316      | 27    | 99    | 1001
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a windowed `ROW_NUMBER()` function with a `PARTITION` on the `LocId` and `BinId`, ordering by the `TransId` `DESC`, and taking just the first result:

```
;With Cte As
(
    Select  *,
            Row_Number() Over (Partition By LocId, BinId Order By TransId Desc) As RN
    From    YourTable
)
Select  TicketId, LocId, BinId, TransId
From    Cte
Where   RN = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Have I missed something, it seems like a [GROUP BY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) will do the trick?

```
SELECT TicketId, LocId, BinId, MAX(TransId)
FROM Table
GROUP BY TicketId, LocId, BinId
```

You mentioned for a given TicketId, an example with a [WHERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188047.aspx) statement.

```
SELECT TicketId, LocId, BinId, MAX(TransId)
FROM Table
WHERE TicketId = 316
GROUP BY TicketId, LocId, BinId
```